# How to validate multiple email with kendo validator?

Tags: validation, mvvm, data-binding, kendo-ui, kendo-validator

I would like to validate the email addresses with input html kendo.
This is my html code:

```
<label for="doc" class="required">E-mail</label>
<input type="email" multiple pattern="^([\w+-.%]+@[\w-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4},*[\W]*)+$" value="" data-bind="value: mail" id="doc" name="mail" required data-email-msg="Email format is not valid" />
```

I would like the addresses to be separated by a comma, but this doesn't work!is not validate for kendo

[image]

Comment: Obviously, this is not going to work! If you want to validate multiple email addresses in a single input box then you would need to create kenod custom validator rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is working [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/tx2jugn1/) to validate multiple emails in a single input field separated by semicolon.

For this I have created a custom Kendo validator rule. The code snippet from the DEMO is show below:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="k-textbox" name="Email" id="Email" required data-required-msg="Please enter atleast one email" data-multipleemails-msg="Some of the Entered Email ids are invalid"/>
```

**JS:**

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}

                $(function () {
                    var container = $("#employeeForm");
                    kendo.init(container);
                    container.kendoValidator({
                        rules: {
                            multipleemails: function (input) {
                                if (input.is("[data-multipleemails-msg]") && input.val() != "")
                                {                                   
                                  var emailsArray = input.val().split(";");
                                    for (var i=0; i < emailsArray.length; i++)
                                    {
                                      //alert(emailsArray[i]);
                                      //return validateEmail(emailsArray[i].trim());
                                        if ((emailsArray[i].trim() != "") && (validateEmail(emailsArray[i].trim()) == false))
                                      {
                                          return false;
                                      }
                                    }

                                }

                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });


                $('#save').click(function() {
                //alert('save');
                    var validator = $("#employeeForm").data("kendoValidator");
                    if (validator.validate()) {
                        alert("Form is successfully validated");
                    }

                });
```